# how to match a relative url that exclude specific word between '/'?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I try it hardly above three days.

the requirement of pattern will match

```
/clubb/clubindex
/cclub/clubindex
/cllub/clubindex
/anyword/clubindex
```

but not `/club/clubindex`, just only exclude `/club/clubindex`.

I use negative lookahead and try to reslove it.

Comment: please add the negative lookahead u used

Comment: What do you want the pattern to do specifically? What rules makes it match the first three examples and then fail on the fourth? What is the code/pattern you are using currently? What is it producing, and what do you want it to produce? What do you want us to do about it? Is there even a question here?

Comment: without more information ; one could say that this pattern matches all sample : `"/(clubb|cclub|cllub)/clubindex"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i do not describe clearly.

the pattern will only filter 'club' controller, i think i found the solution.

```
^/(?<controller>(?!club/).*)/(?<action>.*)$
```

[image]

if want to filter other controller, you can do like this:

[image]

thanks everyone that care about my question.